# Конвертация HTML в PDF на C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf

Какие сейчас существуют бесплатные библиотеки для конвертации HTML в PDF? Лучше всего если это все работает с ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Посмотрите [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538118/Конвертация-html-в-pdf-средствами-c/552564#552564), я уже отвечал на данный вопрос.