# Как конвертировать html в pdf

Tags: c#, html, winforms, pdf

Всем привет. Есть необходимость конвретировать html в pdf, несколько html в 1 pdf документ. И достаточно много есть бесплатных библиотек .NET для этого. Подскажите, кто с какой работал и может кто посоветует с какой библиотекой работаь, потому что подводных комней вообще не знаю, которые могут быть? Спасибо

Comment: https://m.habr.com/ru/post/112707/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552564/179763